# Prettyfaces with Seam beans

Tags: jsf, seam, prettyfaces

Trying to solve this problem for two days without any luck.
The problem occur when i try to define a url-mapping in pretty-config.xml that relay on a bean created with Seam

```
<url-mapping id="test">
    <pattern>/test/#{testBean.param}</pattern>
    <view-id>/test.faces</view-id>
</url-mapping>
```

bean source:

```
package com.web.jsfbean;

import org.jboss.seam.ScopeType;
import org.jboss.seam.annotations.Create;
import org.jboss.seam.annotations.Name;
import org.jboss.seam.annotations.Scope;

@Name("testBean")
@Scope(ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
public class Test {
    private String param;

    @Create
    public void init() {
        param = "initialized";
    }

    public String getParam() {
        return param;
    }

    public void setParam(String param) {
        this.param = param;
    }
}
```

if i define this bean in faces-config everything works as expected.

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

This specific issue has been fixed in versions 3.0.1 of PrettyFaces:

Now, when using Seam 2.x, you would use the following type of mapping:

```
<url-mapping id="test">
        <pattern>/test/#{ paramName }</pattern>
        <view-id>/test.faces</view-id>
</url-mapping>
```

Then you would access this using the Seam @RequestParameter("paramName") annotation.

```
@Name("testBean") @Scope(ScopeType.CONVERSATION) public class Test {

    @RequestParameter("paramName")
    private String param;

    @Create
    public void init() {
        param = "initialized";
    }

    public String getParam() {
        return param;
    }

    public void setParam(String param) {
        this.param = param;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the problem you are experiencing? I'm intrigued by this. PrettyFaces should work with Seam. Try posting your question on the users group: http://groups.google.com/group/prettyfaces-users

Answer (score -1):

Check out JAX-RS. Jersey is the RI and I personally use JBoss's offering (RESTEasy.) This framework will let you do what you want to do a little more simply.

Answer (score -1):

It is supposed to work with Seam, try changing the order of your filters in **web.xml**.

Seam does bundle [UrlRewriteFilter](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.0.GA/reference/en-US/html/configuration.html#configuration.filters.rewrite) if all you are after is bookmarking.